# Preset the value in CAtiveForm with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, yii

Previously I've create a page with dropdownlist and text field with CActiveForm.

```
<?php
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'frm-add-payment-modes',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,                 
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'class'=>'form-horizontal',
    )
));
?>
<div class="row">                           
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label mbs mts" for=""><?php echo Yii::t ('AdminModule.yii', 'adm.sttng.paymentStting.status'); ?> *</label> 
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList ($modelEconfigPaypal, 'active', array('0' => 'Inactive', '1' => 'Active'), array ('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside javascript I've a button function which will return the value.

```
__octAppEditObj.makeAjaxRequest (__basePath + '/admin/settings/getPaymentDetails', data, function (res) {
    var result = JSON.parse(res);
    console.log(result[0]);

    document.getElementById("EconfigPaypal_name").value = result[0]['name'];
    document.getElementById("EconfigPaypal_payment_gateway").value = result[0]['payment_gateway'];
    document.getElementById("EconfigPaypal_payment_gateway_id").value = result[0]['payment_gateway_id'];
    document.getElementById("EconfigPaypal_apiusername").value = result[0]['apiusername'];
    document.getElementById("EconfigPaypal_apipassword").value = result[0]['apipassword'];
    document.getElementById("EconfigPaypal_active").value = result[0]['active'];
    document.getElementById("EconfigPaypal_apilive").value = result[0]['apilive'];
    document.getElementById("EconfigPaypal_apisignature").value = result[0]['apisignature'];
    document.getElementById("EconfigPaypal_string1").value = result[0]['string1'];
    document.getElementById("EconfigPaypal_string2").value = result[0]['string2'];
    document.getElementById("EconfigPaypal_string3").value = result[0]['string3'];
});
```

The method is no issue cause all the text field was able to preset the value. However, the dropdownlist can't. May I know how to preset the value for CActiveform dropdownlist?

Comment: If it does not work for dropdown, share us the code of this dropdown.

Comment: @rob006 sorry, just edit on first figure.

Comment: Your code should work correctly, make sure that you don't have errors in different places (like more elements with this ID) and `result[0]['active']` has correct value.